# Cross-platform PSQL execution from CLI

Tags: postgresql, cmd, sh

I want to execute the following code from the command-line:

```
DO $$ BEGIN EXECUTE ns.proc(); END $$;
```

Because I'm using this in a shell script, I have to escape the `$$`, otherwise they are translated to the process ID. So my code becomes:

```
DO \$\$ BEGIN EXECUTE ns.proc(); END \$\$;
```

Due to the nature of how the shell script is processed, it is run with `/bin/sh` on our production system and with `cmd.exe` on our Windows development systems.

The script will fail on the latter, because `\$\$` isn't translated to `$$`.

Is there a different way to form the statement or can I escape the `$$` in a different way that will work on both platforms? I would really like to avoid having to write the statement to a file.

Comment: Dollar quoting isn't limited to `$$` you can also use e.g. `$body$` or `$foobar$`. If that isn't expanded to the process ID you can use that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It isn't expanded to the PID, but I end up with a plain `$` and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Then I guess your only solution **is** to use a SQL file.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Fair enough :)

Comment: Wouldn't `'DD $$ BEGIN EXECUTE ns.proc(); END $$;'` work in either?

Comment: As an aside, how are you writing a script that runs under both `sh` and `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @chepner It's run through NodeJS and uses `child_process.exec`.